# Why doesn't this javascript code for a basic canvas operation work?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Why does the following code not display a black box on the screen. It titles the page Chatroom so at least the beginning part works...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chatroom</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id=“chatroom” width=“240 height=“400”></canvas>
<script>
const canvas= document.getElementById('chatroom');
const context=canvas.getContext('2d');

context.fillStyle ='#000';
context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all your “ to ": those are different characters, and you need to use the second one in html.

You are also missing a " after 240.

Comment: Thank you! sorry but what do you mean by "to"?

Comment: you are using the character “. You need to use the character ". Those are different, maybe your font doesn't show it but on mine you can see a subtle difference.

Answer (score 0):

see the attributes. u havent quoted them properly.

width="240"